# Embedded mp4 video on a PowerPoint presenation not playing

Tags: powerpoint

We have a presentation (pptx) inside a Document Library. When this file is opened, we have it set to run within the browser (PowerPoint Web App). When it gets to the slide containing the MP4 video, we get this message on the toolbar:

*We can't play the media in this presentation because it's larger than the file size limit set on this service.*

- Video plays fine when opened from the PowerPoint desktop app
- The file size (56 MB) is way below the limit of our Document Library (250 MB)
- We tried it on different browsers (IE11, Edge, Chrome) with the same results
- Tried using Handbrake to compress and change the codec to no avail

Any ideas welcome to get this video playing within the web app. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted -  because i like when people find these kind of edge cases, and appear to have tried troubleshooting it themselves and provide their observations,

Comment: Thanks James Randal, i appreciate your upvote. I posted our resolution below. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out. In HandBrake, we used the preset of Fast 480p30. It further reduced the file size to less than 49MB. The video now plays within PowerPoint Web App with little to no degradation in quality.

Comment: Good on ya - You can mark it as the answer !